# how to open specific infowindow on page load in Fusion Table Layers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am creating a map of some locations in Fusion Table Layers.
I am using an example: http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-simple.html

How can I open a specific infowindow on page load? How can I call to a specific row in Fusion table?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open an InfoWindow on page load, you can simply do that in a javascript function that is called on page load (see at the end of the initialize() function below).

To get only specific rows from a fusion table, you can add the "where" parameter to the FusionTablesLayer-query, see code below.

I modified the example you referred to, to show these two things:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FusionTableLayer with WHERE clause and InfoWindow</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {

            var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.948766, -87.691497);

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                center: chicago,
                zoom: 11,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                query: {
                    select: 'address',
                    from: '198945',
                    where: 'ridership > 5000'
                }
            });
            layer.setMap(map);

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infoWindow.setContent('Hello Chicago!');
            infoWindow.setPosition(chicago);
            infoWindow.open(map);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px; height:400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

More Information about InfoWindows and Fusion Tables:

- [Open InfoWindow on query](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/open_infowindow)
- [Tutorial "Map sample data with Fusion Tables"](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1244603)